# File permission problems with PHP

Tags: php, apache, fopen, mkdir

I am trying to create a folder and `fopen` a file inside that folder.

`mkdir` works fine for creating the folder (as the parent folder has 777 permission), but the resulting folder is owned by user id 99 while the script itself is running under cpanel with user id 32024. Now when I try to create a file inside this folder, I get:

> SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 32024 is not allowed to access /<path_of_file>/<folder_created_by_php> owned by uid 99

This error is fully justifiable as I am trying to write to a folder owned by someone else but how can a script running under 32024 create a folder with owner as 99? Anything wrong with the way server is behaving? Any ideas?

Comment: Your  problem is the safe_mode. If you are running on a PLESK based server (which is where i usually see this problem) ask the webhoster to remove SAFE_MODE for your domain because it is causing issues to your development. If not, change host, go for a CPANEL based host, they are less restrictive and as easy and secure...:)

Comment: Its already on Cpanel. Does enabling safe mode creating this problem of wrong file owner?

Comment: CPanel has safe_mode settings? Disable that man, you don't need safe_mode on cpanel as most if not all servers i know of use SuExec or a similar pattern to work in a completly secure environment...

Comment: Actually, Mathieu, this file will be run by many users over the internet. So I won't be able to change their server settings. Is there any work around for creating the file with same owner id or disabling Safe mode is the only option? Thank you for you time and effort Mathieu.

Comment: The problem is not your file, it's the server. It's part of development, you'll have to ask your users to create the folder before, set it writable and then any files you write will be written correctly. AFAIK, safe_mode is disable on all good webhosting companies, i would put that as a requirement as it is regarded by PHP evangelists and developers as a very bad feature to be removed in PHP6...

Comment: Thank you for that information on safe mode Mathieu. I think, then the only way is to assume that Safe mode will be disabled at the end user side. Do you think that this problem is a result of running PHP in safe mode plus running SuExec or just the safe mode is causing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is related to the safe mode setting on php:

Check this out for more information: http://www.serverschool.com/dedicated-servers/what-is-php-safe-mode/ You'll have all the information to understand what is safe mode actually...

Just ask for your developers NOT to use safe_mode as it is a features unrecommended on all servers these days...

Comment: Thank you Mathieu Dumoulin for all those information that you have provided. This will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to include both users 99 and 32024 to the same group and chmod('yourfilename', 0775) after you create that file

Comment: This file will be run by many users over the internet. So I won't be able to change their server settings. Is there any work around for creating the file with same owner id other than making changes to the server or changing settings on server is inevitable?